# Fix Header in Responsive Shopify Theme

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, shopify

When I look at my site on a phone or simply narrow the browser window on my computer, the elements in the header and the links wind up going behind the main page image.  Here's the link to the page: http://www.sleepfullnights.com/

How do I go about fixing the header on the Shopify page so that it compresses nicely?  I think this is an issue that comes up on multiple pages so any general guidelines for building responsive pages is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**[`@media`](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/media-queries/)** queries is what you're looking for. With them, you can declare different styling to be applied to a page depending on the screen size.

An example of how you can use it:

```
/* apply code below on screens smaller than 1001px in width */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1000px) {
    ul li { font-size:11px; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

can you put the css code for the header?

also you can give a try to bootstrap framwork, it's wery usefull for building responsive websites.

take a look: http://getbootstrap.com/